# Creating system for noting secondary source in block quotation while preserving original source citations. New edition of previously published work

Tags: writing-style, citation, cmos

Working with a text that makes extensive use of a secondary source that will be given in block quotation and, of course, cited. The secondary source, however, contained many original source citations which are to be included here as well. We'll note the secondary source, and not go straight to the original source, as this is a new edition of a previously published work for which the author was known to draw from that secondary source, and often he did so verbatim.

Effectively distinguishing for the reader between these various sources within the block quotation is the issue. In the original 1950s edition, the author and editor (at OUP, no less) were a tad bit careless with their citations, and some of what the author, who was not an academic, used from the secondary source was reproduced verbatim but sometimes without quotation marks or without being set in block quotation.

This is to be corrected in the new edition where all excerpted material must be clearly presented as such. For a lengthy passage taken from a secondary source, block quotation will now be used but it is crucial to note the original source citations as well.

So the question is, how to do this exactly? Using numbered note references for a paragraph in block quotation with, for example, three internal original citations gives us the problem of the final fourth citation reference number calling out the secondary source for the whole passage, coming last and not being readily distinguishable as the secondary source encompassing all the other citations. I believe we want the reader to know this first and then having any internal original citations noted.

I've considered possible solutions such as having the end of the block quotation (a secondary source) followed by an Arabic reference number to note the secondary source, and then for all the internal original citations to use symbols as reference marks.

Historiography is important in this republished text but I'm unsatisfied with the way of presenting distinctions between sources (secondary and original) given in Chicago style, as well as between source citations and discursive/substantive notes. All notes are to be given as sidenotes (margin notes) in this work.

To find an example of how another publisher handled a similar text in an effective and elegant manner that still largely conforms to CMOS would be invaluable at this stage.

All input and clarifying questions welcome. Thank you.

Comment: My sympathies for what sounds like a challenging task. When I've done editing in APA, the guidance has been minimal - in brief, they suggest keeping the citations as-is in the quoted text, but omitting footnotes/endnotes and citations at the end of a quoted text. I'll see if I notice this practice in any books I read. That wouldn't be adequate for what you're describing. The symbol-as-reference-mark idea sounds familiar, but I can't think of an example offhand.

Comment: This might be more suited for Academia SE.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem is due to one quotation to a later source containing **more than one** internal quotation to earlier sources? If it were only one, the matter could be handled by saying in a footnote something like 'Smith . . ., quoting Jones, . . .', couldn't it?

Comment: Please provide an example; all those words make my eyes glaze over.

Comment: Thank you firstly for the responses. I'll try to add an example below, which will have to be lengthy, and therefore not able to fit as a comment. The symbol as reference mark is just the very old convention of asterisk (*), dagger (†), double dagger (‡), and (usually) section mark (§) in that order and if more are needed on the page, they can be doubled up (**, ††, ‡‡, §§). I infrequently see Arabic numeral reference marks and symbols used together, but it does happen. An example that comes to mind is Keith Houston's Shady Characters (2014) where you can see the first instance on p. 7.

Comment: So in my case, here's an example from the book I'm struggling with. Just for the forum, the Arabic reference numbers are in brackets. The first part here is body text:

When, in the Stone Age, metals were discovered and an attempt was made to introduce them into general use, quite an uproar must have arisen and divided people into those who accepted it, and the many who rejected it. Argument and hesitation have continued; almost up to the present day, and we can still perceive faint reverberations of this struggle. According to [Here begins the block quotation from secondary author Stern]

Comment: [BLOCK] the Biblical story of the building of Solomon’s temple, the sound of iron tools was not heard,* and the Mormon temple had still to be built without iron. No bolts of iron were permitted in the repair of the Publican Bridge across the Tiber as late as the fall of the Roman Republic.† Stone knives were used by the Jews for circumcision and by Egyptians for embalming long after they had become familiar with iron. The first successful cast-iron plow, invented in the US in 1797, was rejected by farmers on the theory that cast iron poisoned the lands and stimulated the growth of weeds.‡ [9]

Comment: The footnote I currently have rendered like this:

[9]. Stern, op. cit., p. 54. [Ed. Note: This excerpt from the Stern report contains the following citations, the first two of which were included by Noble:

*1 Kings 6 : 7.

† Ernest W. Burgess, The Function of Socialization in Social Evolution (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1916), p. 16.

‡ Holland Thompson, The Age of Invention (New Haven: Yale University Press, 1921) p. 11. Citation expanded this edition.]

Comment: "I'll see if I notice this practice in any books I read." DId you happen to find anything? I've posted in Academic SE and Writing SE as well. Hard to believe I've landed on something without clearer cut solutions. One recommendation has been to use a reference number on the last line of body text preceding the block quotation. Highly unconventional as all readers are accustomed to the superscripted number applying to what comes before it, not after. But the corresponding note would state it applies to the following block. Urgh.

Answer (score 2):

This breaks the rules of CMOS, but one reasonable approach would be to move the secondary source citation to the sentence *before* the quote. If the secondary source is Smith and the primary source is Perry, you would write, using square brackets to represent superscript:

---

According to Smith:[1]

> Perry says that "he is tired"[2] of all this "nonsense."[3]

[1] - Smith, page 11.

[2] - Perry, page 55.

[3] - Perry, page 56.

Comment: Thank you – this is a reasonable suggestion and would be a possible solution, however, I cannot rewrite the text to provide an opportunity for an introductory/identifying line like "According to Smith". I suppose adding a reference number right at the last line before the block quote might still work, even though the block quote is often introduced with just a fragment that relies on the quote continuing to make sense.

Comment: Is there a particular case when footnote or endnote reference numbers are placed in brackets or parentheses? Is this done in block quotations to distinguish reference numbers contained in the original source from final citation reference number? To be clear, this refers to the superscripted note number in the text.